# Bootstrap modal visibility not responding to button in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using react, with bootstrap installed as an node package. N.B. This is the bootstrap packet, not the react-bootstrap, or reactstrap packet. I've followed the instructions on the bootstrap modal page, to create a modal that is toggled by a button. This exact code has worked for me in the past, but not within a react app, so I am confident that this is the issue.

Button:

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-primary"
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#exampleModal"
>
  Login
</button>
```

Modal:

```
<div
  className="modal fade"
  id="exampleModal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true"
>
  <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
          Modal title
        </h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="close"
          data-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body">...</div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary"
          data-dismiss="modal"
        >
          Close
        </button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
          Save changes
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button renders properly, and so does the modal. Manually switching the modal visibility gives a proper modal, so I can conclude that the issue is in the button toggling the visibility.

Comment: I'd suggest using reactstrap https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/

Comment: @petermk Thanks, but I'd like to do it with regular bootstrap. Also, this is regular css and html, it should work, even with react, no?

Comment: bootstrap uses bootstrap JS to show/hide modals. Are you including bootstrap JS in your project?

Comment: According to the page npmjs.com page, yes, it contains the CSS and the JS. It comes with Popper.  It also requires jQuery, which I have installed